# Hadoop's ResourceManager fails to start when started through Ansible

Tags: hadoop, ansible, hadoop-yarn

I am having trouble starting YARN (via `./start-yarn.sh`) in pseudo-distributed mode when doing it through Ansible.

This is the part of my playbook that starts YARN (where `hadoop_home` is `/home/hdoop/hadoop`):

```yaml
- name: hdoop > Start YARN
  become: true
  become_user: hdoop
  environment:
    HADOOP_HOME: "{{ hadoop_home }}"
    HADOOP_HDFS_HOME: "{{ hadoop_home }}"
    HADOOP_CONF_DIR: "{{ hadoop_home }}/etc/hadoop"
    HADOOP_YARN_HOME: "{{ hadoop_home }}"
  shell: 
    cmd: "{{ hadoop_home }}/sbin/start-yarn.sh"
    executable: /bin/bash
```

Here is my `yarn-site.xml` file:

```xml
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
  <value>0.0.0.0</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
  <value>0.0.0.0:8088</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.acl.enable</name>
  <value>0</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.env-whitelist</name>   
  <value>JAVA_HOME,HADOOP_COMMON_HOME,HADOOP_HDFS_HOME,HADOOP_CONF_DIR,CLASSPATH_PREPEND_DISTCACHE,HADOOP_YARN_HOME,HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

This results in the `NodeManager` starting but not the `ResourceManager`. I get the following error:

```
STARTUP_MSG:   build = Unknown -r 7a3bc90b05f257c8ace2f76d74264906f0f7a932; compiled by 'hexiaoqiao' on 2021-01-03T09:26Z
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.8.0_282
************************************************************/
2021-02-20 18:27:03,040 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2021-02-20 18:27:03,632 INFO org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: found resource core-site.xml at file:/home/hdoop/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml
2021-02-20 18:27:03,736 INFO org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found
2021-02-20 18:27:03,736 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.
2021-02-20 18:27:03,799 INFO org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: found resource yarn-site.xml at file:/home/hdoop/hadoop/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml
2021-02-20 18:27:03,808 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMFatalEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$RMFatalEventDispatcher
2021-02-20 18:27:03,897 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.NMTokenSecretManagerInRM: NMTokenKeyRollingInterval: 86400000ms and NMTokenKeyActivationDelay: 900000ms
2021-02-20 18:27:03,905 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.RMContainerTokenSecretManager: ContainerTokenKeyRollingInterval: 86400000ms and ContainerTokenKeyActivationDelay: 900000ms
2021-02-20 18:27:03,917 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.AMRMTokenSecretManager: AMRMTokenKeyRollingInterval: 86400000ms and AMRMTokenKeyActivationDelay: 900000 ms
2021-02-20 18:27:03,965 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.RMStateStoreEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.RMStateStore$ForwardingEventHandler
2021-02-20 18:27:03,970 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.NodesListManagerEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.NodesListManager
2021-02-20 18:27:03,970 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Using Scheduler: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler
2021-02-20 18:27:04,002 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.event.SchedulerEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.EventDispatcher
2021-02-20 18:27:04,003 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$ApplicationEventDispatcher
2021-02-20 18:27:04,005 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$ApplicationAttemptEventDispatcher
2021-02-20 18:27:04,005 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmnode.RMNodeEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$NodeEventDispatcher
2021-02-20 18:27:04,081 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: Loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2021-02-20 18:27:04,231 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled Metric snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2021-02-20 18:27:04,231 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: ResourceManager metrics system started
2021-02-20 18:27:04,245 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.security.YarnAuthorizationProvider: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.security.ConfiguredYarnAuthorizer is instantiated.
2021-02-20 18:27:04,248 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManagerEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager
2021-02-20 18:27:04,254 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.AMLauncherEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.ApplicationMasterLauncher
2021-02-20 18:27:04,255 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMNMInfo: Registered RMNMInfo MBean
2021-02-20 18:27:04,256 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.monitor.RMAppLifetimeMonitor: Application lifelime monitor interval set to 3000 ms.
2021-02-20 18:27:04,261 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.placement.MultiNodeSortingManager: Initializing NodeSortingService=MultiNodeSortingManager
2021-02-20 18:27:04,262 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.HostsFileReader: Refreshing hosts (include/exclude) list
2021-02-20 18:27:04,285 INFO org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: found resource capacity-scheduler.xml at file:/home/hdoop/hadoop/etc/hadoop/capacity-scheduler.xml
2021-02-20 18:27:04,293 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.AbstractYarnScheduler: Minimum allocation = <memory:1024, vCores:1>
2021-02-20 18:27:04,293 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.AbstractYarnScheduler: Maximum allocation = <memory:8192, vCores:4>
2021-02-20 18:27:04,382 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacitySchedulerConfiguration: max alloc mb per queue for root is undefined
2021-02-20 18:27:04,383 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacitySchedulerConfiguration: max alloc vcore per queue for root is undefined
2021-02-20 18:27:04,407 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.ParentQueue: root, capacity=1.0, absoluteCapacity=1.0, maxCapacity=1.0, absoluteMaxCapacity=1.0, state=RUNNING, acls=SUBMIT_APP:*ADMINISTER_QUEUE:*, labels=*,
, reservationsContinueLooking=true, orderingPolicy=utilization, priority=0
2021-02-20 18:27:04,407 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.ParentQueue: Initialized parent-queue root name=root, fullname=root
2021-02-20 18:27:04,440 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacitySchedulerConfiguration: max alloc mb per queue for root.default is undefined
2021-02-20 18:27:04,440 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacitySchedulerConfiguration: max alloc vcore per queue for root.default is undefined
2021-02-20 18:27:04,444 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.LeafQueue: Initializing default
capacity = 1.0 [= (float) configuredCapacity / 100 ]
absoluteCapacity = 1.0 [= parentAbsoluteCapacity * capacity ]
maxCapacity = 1.0 [= configuredMaxCapacity ]
absoluteMaxCapacity = 1.0 [= 1.0 maximumCapacity undefined, (parentAbsoluteMaxCapacity * maximumCapacity) / 100 otherwise ]
effectiveMinResource=<memory:0, vCores:0>
 , effectiveMaxResource=<memory:0, vCores:0>
userLimit = 100 [= configuredUserLimit ]
userLimitFactor = 1.0 [= configuredUserLimitFactor ]
maxApplications = 10000 [= configuredMaximumSystemApplicationsPerQueue or (int)(configuredMaximumSystemApplications * absoluteCapacity)]
maxApplicationsPerUser = 10000 [= (int)(maxApplications * (userLimit / 100.0f) * userLimitFactor) ]
usedCapacity = 0.0 [= usedResourcesMemory / (clusterResourceMemory * absoluteCapacity)]
absoluteUsedCapacity = 0.0 [= usedResourcesMemory / clusterResourceMemory]
maxAMResourcePerQueuePercent = 0.1 [= configuredMaximumAMResourcePercent ]
minimumAllocationFactor = 0.875 [= (float)(maximumAllocationMemory - minimumAllocationMemory) / maximumAllocationMemory ]
maximumAllocation = <memory:8192, vCores:4> [= configuredMaxAllocation ]
numContainers = 0 [= currentNumContainers ]
state = RUNNING [= configuredState ]
acls = SUBMIT_APP:*ADMINISTER_QUEUE:* [= configuredAcls ]
nodeLocalityDelay = 40
rackLocalityAdditionalDelay = -1
labels=*,
reservationsContinueLooking = true
preemptionDisabled = true
defaultAppPriorityPerQueue = 0
priority = 0
maxLifetime = -1 seconds
defaultLifetime = -1 seconds
2021-02-20 18:27:04,445 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacitySchedulerQueueManager: Initialized queue: default: capacity=1.0, absoluteCapacity=1.0, usedResources=<memory:0, vCores:0>, usedCapacity=0.0, absoluteUsedCapacity=0.0, numApps=0, numContainers=0, effectiveMinResource=<memory:0, vCores:0> , effectiveMaxResource=<memory:0, vCores:0>
2021-02-20 18:27:04,445 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacitySchedulerQueueManager: Initialized queue: root: numChildQueue= 1, capacity=1.0, absoluteCapacity=1.0, usedResources=<memory:0, vCores:0>usedCapacity=0.0, numApps=0, numContainers=0
2021-02-20 18:27:04,452 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacitySchedulerQueueManager: Initialized root queue root: numChildQueue= 1, capacity=1.0, absoluteCapacity=1.0, usedResources=<memory:0, vCores:0>usedCapacity=0.0, numApps=0, numContainers=0
2021-02-20 18:27:04,452 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.placement.UserGroupMappingPlacementRule: Initialized queue mappings, override: false
2021-02-20 18:27:04,452 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.WorkflowPriorityMappingsManager: Initialized workflow priority mappings, override: false
2021-02-20 18:27:04,453 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.placement.MultiNodeSortingManager: MultiNode scheduling is 'false', and configured policies are 
2021-02-20 18:27:04,454 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Initialized CapacityScheduler with calculator=class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DefaultResourceCalculator, minimumAllocation=<<memory:1024, vCores:1>>, maximumAllocation=<<memory:8192, vCores:4>>, asynchronousScheduling=false, asyncScheduleInterval=5ms,multiNodePlacementEnabled=false
2021-02-20 18:27:04,476 INFO org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: dynamic-resources.xml not found
2021-02-20 18:27:04,480 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.AMSProcessingChain: Initializing AMS Processing chain. Root Processor=[org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.DefaultAMSProcessor].
2021-02-20 18:27:04,480 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ApplicationMasterService: disabled placement handler will be used, all scheduling requests will be rejected.
2021-02-20 18:27:04,481 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.AMSProcessingChain: Adding [org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.constraint.processor.DisabledPlacementProcessor] tp top of AMS Processing chain. 
2021-02-20 18:27:04,502 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: TimelineServicePublisher is not configured
2021-02-20 18:27:04,584 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.util.log: Logging initialized @2275ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
2021-02-20 18:27:04,943 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter: Unable to initialize FileSignerSecretProvider, falling back to use random secrets.
2021-02-20 18:27:04,980 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpRequestLog: Http request log for http.requests.resourcemanager is not defined
2021-02-20 18:27:05,006 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added global filter 'safety' (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2$QuotingInputFilter)
2021-02-20 18:27:05,018 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter RMAuthenticationFilter (class=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.security.http.RMAuthenticationFilter) to context cluster
2021-02-20 18:27:05,018 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter RMAuthenticationFilter (class=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.security.http.RMAuthenticationFilter) to context static
2021-02-20 18:27:05,018 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter RMAuthenticationFilter (class=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.security.http.RMAuthenticationFilter) to context logs
2021-02-20 18:27:05,018 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context cluster
2021-02-20 18:27:05,018 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context static
2021-02-20 18:27:05,018 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context logs
2021-02-20 18:27:05,021 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: adding path spec: /cluster/*
2021-02-20 18:27:05,021 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: adding path spec: /ws/*
2021-02-20 18:27:05,021 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: adding path spec: /app/*
2021-02-20 18:27:06,588 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps: Registered webapp guice modules
2021-02-20 18:27:06,625 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Jetty bound to port 8088
2021-02-20 18:27:06,628 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server: jetty-9.4.20.v20190813; built: 2019-08-13T21:28:18.144Z; git: 84700530e645e812b336747464d6fbbf370c9a20; jvm 1.8.0_282-8u282-b08-0ubuntu1~20.04-b08
2021-02-20 18:27:06,716 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.session: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2021-02-20 18:27:06,716 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.session: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2021-02-20 18:27:06,721 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.session: node0 Scavenging every 660000ms
2021-02-20 18:27:06,763 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter: Unable to initialize FileSignerSecretProvider, falling back to use random secrets.
2021-02-20 18:27:06,798 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Updating the current master key for generating delegation tokens
2021-02-20 18:27:06,819 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Starting expired delegation token remover thread, tokenRemoverScanInterval=60 min(s)
2021-02-20 18:27:06,836 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Updating the current master key for generating delegation tokens
2021-02-20 18:27:06,906 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6cb6decd{logs,/logs,file:///home/hdoop/hadoop/logs/,AVAILABLE}
2021-02-20 18:27:06,915 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@30bce90b{static,/static,jar:file:/home/hdoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-3.2.2.jar!/webapps/static,AVAILABLE}
2021-02-20 18:27:06,935 WARN org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration: Can't generate resourceBase as part of webapp tmp dir name: java.lang.NullPointerException
2021-02-20 18:27:07,382 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.util.TypeUtil: JVM Runtime does not support Modules
2021-02-20 18:27:12,831 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: RECEIVED SIGNAL 1: SIGHUP
2021-02-20 18:27:15,009 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@4016ccc1{cluster,/,file:///tmp/jetty-0_0_0_0-8088-_-any-3811097377054804183.dir/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{jar:file:/home/hdoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-3.2.2.jar!/webapps/cluster}
2021-02-20 18:27:15,048 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Started ServerConnector@1bd39d3c{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8088}
2021-02-20 18:27:15,048 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server: Started @12739ms
2021-02-20 18:27:15,048 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps: Web app cluster started at 8088
2021-02-20 18:27:15,277 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.CallQueueManager: Using callQueue: class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue, queueCapacity: 100, scheduler: class org.apache.hadoop.ipc.DefaultRpcScheduler, ipcBackoff: false.
2021-02-20 18:27:15,327 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 8033
2021-02-20 18:27:15,771 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl: Adding protocol org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.api.ResourceManagerAdministrationProtocolPB to the server
2021-02-20 18:27:15,773 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Transitioning to active state
2021-02-20 18:27:15,772 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2021-02-20 18:27:15,773 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 8033: starting
2021-02-20 18:27:15,818 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.RMStateStore: Updating AMRMToken
2021-02-20 18:27:15,821 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.RMContainerTokenSecretManager: Rolling master-key for container-tokens
2021-02-20 18:27:15,822 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.NMTokenSecretManagerInRM: Rolling master-key for nm-tokens
2021-02-20 18:27:15,822 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Updating the current master key for generating delegation tokens
2021-02-20 18:27:15,822 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.RMDelegationTokenSecretManager: storing master key with keyID 1
2021-02-20 18:27:15,822 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.RMStateStore: Storing RMDTMasterKey.
2021-02-20 18:27:15,833 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Starting expired delegation token remover thread, tokenRemoverScanInterval=60 min(s)
2021-02-20 18:27:15,833 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Updating the current master key for generating delegation tokens
2021-02-20 18:27:15,834 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.RMDelegationTokenSecretManager: storing master key with keyID 2
2021-02-20 18:27:15,834 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.RMStateStore: Storing RMDTMasterKey.
2021-02-20 18:27:15,835 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.nodelabels.event.NodeLabelsStoreEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.nodelabels.CommonNodeLabelsManager$ForwardingEventHandler
2021-02-20 18:27:16,227 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.nodelabels.store.AbstractFSNodeStore: Created store directory :file:/tmp/hadoop-yarn-hdoop/node-attribute
2021-02-20 18:27:16,297 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.nodelabels.store.AbstractFSNodeStore: Finished write mirror at:file:/tmp/hadoop-yarn-hdoop/node-attribute/nodeattribute.mirror
2021-02-20 18:27:16,297 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.nodelabels.store.AbstractFSNodeStore: Finished create editlog file at:file:/tmp/hadoop-yarn-hdoop/node-attribute/nodeattribute.editlog
2021-02-20 18:27:16,319 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.nodelabels.NodeAttributesStoreEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.nodelabels.NodeAttributesManagerImpl$ForwardingEventHandler
2021-02-20 18:27:16,322 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.placement.MultiNodeSortingManager: Starting NodeSortingService=MultiNodeSortingManager
2021-02-20 18:27:16,363 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.CallQueueManager: Using callQueue: class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue, queueCapacity: 5000, scheduler: class org.apache.hadoop.ipc.DefaultRpcScheduler, ipcBackoff: false.
2021-02-20 18:27:16,364 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 8031
2021-02-20 18:27:16,384 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl: Adding protocol org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.api.ResourceTrackerPB to the server
2021-02-20 18:27:16,394 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2021-02-20 18:27:16,434 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 8031: starting
2021-02-20 18:27:16,455 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.JvmPauseMonitor: Starting JVM pause monitor
2021-02-20 18:27:16,496 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.CallQueueManager: Using callQueue: class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue, queueCapacity: 5000, scheduler: class org.apache.hadoop.ipc.DefaultRpcScheduler, ipcBackoff: false.
2021-02-20 18:27:16,501 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 8030
2021-02-20 18:27:16,528 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl: Adding protocol org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.ApplicationMasterProtocolPB to the server
2021-02-20 18:27:16,529 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2021-02-20 18:27:16,529 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 8030: starting
2021-02-20 18:27:16,721 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.CallQueueManager: Using callQueue: class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue, queueCapacity: 5000, scheduler: class org.apache.hadoop.ipc.DefaultRpcScheduler, ipcBackoff: false.
2021-02-20 18:27:16,722 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 8032
2021-02-20 18:27:16,725 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl: Adding protocol org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.ApplicationClientProtocolPB to the server
2021-02-20 18:27:16,742 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 8032: starting
2021-02-20 18:27:16,763 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Transitioned to active state
2021-02-20 18:27:16,763 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2021-02-20 18:27:16,766 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: ExpiredTokenRemover received java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
2021-02-20 18:27:16,769 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@4016ccc1{cluster,/,null,UNAVAILABLE}{jar:file:/home/hdoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-3.2.2.jar!/webapps/cluster}
2021-02-20 18:27:16,785 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Stopped ServerConnector@1bd39d3c{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8088}
2021-02-20 18:27:16,786 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.session: node0 Stopped scavenging
2021-02-20 18:27:16,791 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@30bce90b{static,/static,jar:file:/home/hdoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-3.2.2.jar!/webapps/static,UNAVAILABLE}
2021-02-20 18:27:16,791 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6cb6decd{logs,/logs,file:///home/hdoop/hadoop/logs/,UNAVAILABLE}
2021-02-20 18:27:16,795 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping server on 8032
2021-02-20 18:27:16,811 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server listener on 8032
2021-02-20 18:27:16,821 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server Responder
2021-02-20 18:27:16,822 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping server on 8033
2021-02-20 18:27:16,822 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server listener on 8033
2021-02-20 18:27:16,825 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Transitioning to standby state
2021-02-20 18:27:16,825 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.ApplicationMasterLauncher: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.ApplicationMasterLauncher$LauncherThread interrupted. Returning.
2021-02-20 18:27:16,826 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server Responder
2021-02-20 18:27:16,827 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping server on 8030
2021-02-20 18:27:16,839 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server listener on 8030
2021-02-20 18:27:16,841 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server Responder
2021-02-20 18:27:16,847 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping server on 8031
2021-02-20 18:27:16,862 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server listener on 8031
2021-02-20 18:27:16,863 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server Responder
2021-02-20 18:27:16,863 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.AbstractLivelinessMonitor: NMLivelinessMonitor thread interrupted
2021-02-20 18:27:16,868 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.EventDispatcher: Returning, interrupted : java.lang.InterruptedException
2021-02-20 18:27:16,868 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.activities.ActivitiesManager: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.activities.ActivitiesManager thread interrupted
2021-02-20 18:27:16,869 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: AsyncDispatcher is draining to stop, ignoring any new events.
2021-02-20 18:27:16,870 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: AsyncDispatcher is draining to stop, ignoring any new events.
2021-02-20 18:27:16,870 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.AbstractLivelinessMonitor: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.monitor.RMAppLifetimeMonitor thread interrupted
2021-02-20 18:27:16,873 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.AbstractLivelinessMonitor: AMLivelinessMonitor thread interrupted
2021-02-20 18:27:16,873 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.AbstractLivelinessMonitor: AMLivelinessMonitor thread interrupted
2021-02-20 18:27:16,874 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.AbstractLivelinessMonitor: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmcontainer.ContainerAllocationExpirer thread interrupted
2021-02-20 18:27:16,875 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: ExpiredTokenRemover received java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
2021-02-20 18:27:16,878 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping ResourceManager metrics system...
2021-02-20 18:27:16,879 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: ResourceManager metrics system stopped.
2021-02-20 18:27:16,879 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: ResourceManager metrics system shutdown complete.
2021-02-20 18:27:16,879 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: AsyncDispatcher is draining to stop, ignoring any new events.
2021-02-20 18:27:16,881 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Transitioned to standby state
2021-02-20 18:27:16,882 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down ResourceManager at hadoop-1/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
```

At this point, a call to `jps` tells me that `ResourceManager` was not started:

```
hdoop@hadoop-1:~/hadoop/logs$ jps
18372 DataNode
18537 SecondaryNameNode
18282 NameNode
19549 Jps
18927 NodeManager
```

The curious part is that when I start it myself through a terminal, it runs just fine.

Does anyone know what's going on? Or why `ResourceManager` refuses to start under Ansible?

Comment: Unclear where that log output is coming from, but the [SIGHUP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP) in that text is pretty self-explanatory; you'll want `shell: nohup {{ hadoop_home }}/sbin/start-yarn.sh &` or switch to a for-real service manager to make your playbook idempotent

Comment: Ansible `shell` module is not designed to launch commands that are supposed to run in the background, it's mostly just an elegant `ssh target -c 'value_of_cmd'`, so once the command returns, the ssh connection ends and the processes launched during the session are stopped. Like suggested, you can use nohup, but a better solution would be to create a service launching yarn and start it with the `service` module.

Comment: @mdaniel your explanation on SIGHUP seems to make sense. However, without ansible, I can run the command `start-dfs.sh` in the terminal and logout, and yarn would continue running since it's started in daemon mode

Answer (score 0):

yarn executable in $HADOOP_HOME/bin/yarn should be used.

Eg.:

```
- name: Start Yarn Cluster
  command: '{{ item }}'
  with_items:
    - "nohup {{ HADOOP_HOME }}/bin/yarn --daemon start resourcemanager"
    - "nohup {{ HADOOP_HOME }}/bin/yarn --daemon start nodemanager"
  become: yes
  become_method: su
  become_user: ubuntu
  environment: "{{ proxy_env }}"
```